# Where is the password never expires setting for local users on Windows Server 2019

Tags: passwords, windows-server

On Windows Server 2019 it just prompted me to change my password because it is due to expire. This is a local user (not an AD user) and I don't want the password to expire for this user (it has a strong, randomized password).

I looked around in the UI but I couldn't find a way to do this. How is this done in Server 2019?

Answer (score 0):

The command line has come to the rescue! Simply open a Command Prompt (I did it in Administrator mode), and enter:

```
wmic UserAccount where Name='username' set PasswordExpires=False
```

(obv. replace username with the real username)